# Enumerating $m\times n$ binary matrices with constant column sum and at least one non-zero row entry

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I have worked out the following, and would appreciate if anyone can verify or suggest improvements.

If the columns should sum up to $k$, then there are $\binom{m}{k}^n$ $m\times n$-matrices with a column sum of $k$.

Let $d_j$ denote the number of matrices of $j$ rows with at least a non-zero entry but column sum equal to $k$ (and $j \geq k$), then the rest of $m-j$ rows are zeroes and can be chosen in $\binom{m}{m-j} $ ways, thus
$$\sum_{j=k}^{m} \binom{m}{m-j}d_j = \binom{m}{k}^n$$

Using Binomial inversion formula we find that
$$d_m = \sum_{j=k}^{m} (-1)^{m-j} \binom{m}{j} \binom{j}{k}^n $$

Comment: What's $t{}{}$?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been $m$. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the order of summation yields
$$d_m = \sum_{j=k}^{m} (-1)^{m-j} \binom{m}{j} \binom{j}{k}^n
= \sum_{r=0}^{m-k} (-1)^r \binom{m}{m-r} \binom{m-r}{k}^n
= \sum_{r=0}^{m-k} (-1)^r \binom{m}{r} \binom{m-r}{k}^n.
$$
You can obtain this last summation directly as the inclusion-exclusion formula for $m \times n$ binary matrices with column sum $k$ that avoid the $m$ properties that row $i$ is all zero.